# How not to change the parent NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

I have one NSMutableArray and I want just to copy it to another NSMutableArray and change the second one

Example code

```
let one: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
one.addObject(9);

var two: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

two = one;
two.addObject(4);
one.addObject(2);

println(two); // "(\n    9,\n    4,\n    2\n)" - the 2 should not be here
println(one);// "(\n    9,\n    4,\n    2\n)" - the 4 should not be here
```

I try

```
two = one.copy() as! NSMutableArray; // but this give an error
```

// Update
// If instead a simple number there is NSMutableDictionary

```
let one: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    let dic: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary();
    dic["type"] = "free";
    dic["value"] = i;
    one.addObject(dic);
}

var two: NSMutableArray = one.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray;

two[0].setObject("used", forKey: "type");
println(two);
println(one); // one[0] - used, but it should be free
```

Comment: You want `mutableCopy`.  Copy returns an immutable copy!  :P

Comment: but if i use NSMutableDictionary instead just a number its is changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// This is how to copy the old array

```
let two: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: one);
```

Comment: This is about [reference types vs value types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10).